# Embedded HTML movie (mp4) cannot be viewed by iphone

Tags: html, iphone, mp4

I am using the following codes to display mp4 movies on my website

```
<video  width=340 height=260 preload=metadata controls=controls>
<source src="http://www.xxxxx.com/gxxxxxx.mp4">
</video>
```

It works fine in my PC, but when it is viewed by a iphone /ipad, it doesn't work. (just a black screen without playing)

What is wrong with my codes ?

Answer (score 0):

For iOS devices (iphone / ipad) Please note that you must place you video files in a website with SSL (in my understanding it is the requirement by Apple).

Then you may use your codes with the following small amendment:

```
<video  width=340 height=260 preload=metadata controls=controls>
<source src="https://www.xxxxx.com/gxxxxxx.mp4">
</video>
```

The interesting thing is, if the website is not SSL protected, but as long as the source src of the movie is residing in a https site, it will still work. Please try

Comment: Thanks. I tested placing the mp4 in a SSL site and it can be viewed in my iphone. That's really a strange requirement by Apple.